# How to find important words using TfIdfVectorizer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

Consider the below example. the important words which represent the documents are 'Bob' and 'Sara'. but with the `max_features`, the output tends to show frequent words. This will get worse when the corpus is big. How can we only get the important words?

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import pandas as pd


corpus = [
    'hi, my name is Bob.',
    'hi, my name is Sara.'
]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=2)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus).todense()


df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

The output:

```
,hi,is
0,0.7071067811865475,0.7071067811865475
1,0.7071067811865475,0.7071067811865475
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you increase the max_features:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=10)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus).todense()
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
print(df)
   bob       hi       is       my     name      sara 
0  0.574962  0.40909  0.40909  0.40909  0.40909  0.000000 
1  0.000000  0.40909  0.40909  0.40909  0.40909  0.574962
```

You can see that sara and bob are really important, since tfidf is higher for those and smaller and equal for the other, what makes sense since are repeated in both sentences.

Notice that as in [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html).  As in `max_features`:
"If not None, build a vocabulary that only consider the top max_features ordered by term frequency across the corpus." So it maybe remove the more useful words like in previous case.

Perhaps you may be interested more in the option `max_df` or `min_df`:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.5)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus).todense()
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
print(df)
   bob  sara
0  1.0   0.0
1  0.0   1.0
```

Perhaps is best to try different approach until you get a sense of what is going on.

From another point of view it could be good to remove some of the stop words too.

Comment: Thank you. So the following statement will lead to the 10 important features?
"max_features=10, max_df=0.5"

Comment: Depending on the case. You should play around a bit, until you have a grasp. I increase to maximum of features to see how looks like. Because the problem is so small you could actually use them all.

Comment: I see. But what if the corpus was very large and the differences cannot be seen. Is there a way to do this with high reliability?

Comment: I would stem the words and remove the stop words. After that I would try to  see how many features I could introduce, in terms of computing power and time. After that I will remove some of them. Probably using max_df.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. so you do not recommend the `max_features` parameter, right?

Comment: Yes, I think in that case is not useful, better not to use max_features at the start. Only if you are sure is fine.

Comment: Could you please take a look at this too:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66092089/binary-classification-using-the-n-grams