# Binary Classification using the N-Grams

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, n-gram, tfidfvectorizer

I want to extract the ngrams of the tweets, from two groups of users (0/1), to make a CSV file as follows for a binary classifier.

```
user_tweets, ngram1, ngram2, ngram3, ..., label
1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ..., 0
2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ..., 1
..
```

My question is whether I should first extract the important ngrams of the two groups, and then score each ngram that I found in the user's tweets? or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps this is interesting: https://pythonprogramming.net/words-as-features-nltk-tutorial/

Comment: In this paper https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W12-3704.pdf there are some steps to prepare before that

Comment: The two different approaches.